# Wrap a PPTP/L2TP/OpenVPN VPN server that forwards everything through an SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, vpn, dd-wrt, tunnel

Using say: ssh -D8080 user@remoteserver.com

to create an SSH tunnel to a remote server and use it as a SOCKS proxy, etc.,

how would one go about to wrap it into a VPN server (PPTP, L2TP or OpenVPN), if possible, in order to have devices that do not support tunneling but support VPN (like the iPad or DD-WRT routers) be able to log in to the VPN which will then transparently funnel everything through the SSH tunnel?

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you are intending here.  You want one device to ssh to a remote server to establish the tunnel, but then accept VPN connections to itself for other devices?

Comment: That's right, and then to funnel all packets from devices connected to it by VPN to the ssh tunnel. I think one way of doing this besides setting up a VPN around the tunnel is to use iptables on a router that forwards everything to the ssh tunnel. Not an expert in this by any means though, just guessing.

Comment: But the ssh tunnel as described is still a socks proxy, are all the devices internal and you are just trying to get them *to* the point where the tunnel is?  They would still need to have a proxy defined.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to get them to *use* the tunnel. So for instance, when using Safari on my iPhone it'll access the web through the SOCKS proxy/ssh tunnel setup on my Mac. Is this possible?

Comment: @flow: Putting a bounty on someone else's question is confusing. Please detail your configuration: The devices involved and their operating systems.